# How should I efficiently extract stacktraces from a stream of log messages?

Tags: java

On Android, I have a need to extract stacktraces from a stream of log messages. This hasn't been as simple as I thought it would be. Here's how I access the stream of log messages:

```
Process proLogcat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
BufferedReader bufLogcat = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proLogcat.getInputStream()));
String strLine;
while ((strLine = bufLogcat.readLine()) != null) {
    //Do something with the line
}
```

I simply execute the `logcat` command and read the lines as I don't have direct access to the log file. I'd like to parse out all the stacktraces from log messages that are either errors or warnings and group them accordingly.

I'm wondering how to do this efficiently. A friend suggested using ANTLR but I have no experience with it.

Here's a sample of the the stream that I'm parsing:

```
E/ImageFetcher(14395): Unable download image from the web
E/ImageFetcher(14395): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Server responded with code 404
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at com.mridang.widgets.utils.ImageFetcher.getImage(ImageFetcher.java:64)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at com.mridang.cominup.LauncherWidget.fetchContent(LauncherWidget.java:103)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at com.mridang.widgets.BaseWidget$1.run(BaseWidget.java:384)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W/SlideFactory(14395): Unable to download cover for Nymphomaniac Vol II
E/ImageFetcher(14395): Unable download image from the web
E/ImageFetcher(14395): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Server responded with code 404
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at com.mridang.widgets.utils.ImageFetcher.getImage(ImageFetcher.java:64)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at com.mridang.cominup.LauncherWidget.fetchContent(LauncherWidget.java:103)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at com.mridang.widgets.BaseWidget$1.run(BaseWidget.java:384)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
E/ImageFetcher(14395):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W/SlideFactory(14395): Unable to download cover for Labor Day
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/GCM/DMM ( 3138): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.mridang.computer (has extras) }
W/GCM/DMM ( 3138): Receiver package not found, unregister application com.mridang.computer sender 
W/ContextImpl( 3138): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 eeu.a:321 eez.onReceive:354 
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
E/Sensors ( 2349): Acc old sensor_state 0, new sensor_state : 1 en : 1
E/Sensors ( 2349): Gyro old sensor_state 1, new sensor_state : 3 en : 1
E/Sensors ( 2349): Pressure old sensor_state 3, new sensor_state : 11 en : 1
W/Sidekick_LocationOracleImpl( 3405): Best location was null
E/Sensors ( 2349): Acc old sensor_state 11, new sensor_state : 10 en : 0
E/Sensors ( 2349): Gyro old sensor_state 10, new sensor_state : 8 en : 0
E/Sensors ( 2349): Pressure old sensor_state 8, new sensor_state : 0 en : 0
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/GCM/DMM ( 3138): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.mridang.computer (has extras) }
W/GCM/DMM ( 3138): Receiver package not found, unregister application com.mridang.computer sender 
W/ContextImpl( 3138): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 eeu.a:321 eez.onReceive:354 
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/GCM/DMM ( 3138): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.mridang.computer (has extras) }
W/GCM/DMM ( 3138): Receiver package not found, unregister application com.mridang.computer sender 
W/ContextImpl( 3138): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 eeu.a:321 eez.onReceive:354 
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
E/fb4a(:<default>):AddressResolver(14427): Failed to deserialize to instance com.facebook.mqtt.AddressEntry
E/fb4a(:<default>):AddressResolver(14427):  at [Source: java.io.StringReader@42567cb8; line: 1, column: 34]
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/GCM/DMM ( 3138): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.mridang.computer (has extras) }
W/GCM/DMM ( 3138): Receiver package not found, unregister application com.mridang.computer sender 
W/ContextImpl( 3138): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 eeu.a:321 eez.onReceive:354 
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/GCM/DMM ( 3138): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.mridang.computer (has extras) }
W/GCM/DMM ( 3138): Receiver package not found, unregister application com.mridang.computer sender 
W/ContextImpl( 3138): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 eeu.a:321 eez.onReceive:354 
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/ContentResolver(14595): Failed to get type for: content://com.android.calendar (Unknown URL content://com.android.calendar)
W/n       (14634): [getWeather] Got exception: java.lang.Exception: Couldn't get current location
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/GCM/DMM ( 3138): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.mridang.computer (has extras) }
W/GCM/DMM ( 3138): Receiver package not found, unregister application com.mridang.computer sender 
W/ContextImpl( 3138): Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER (has extras) } android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 eeu.a:321 eez.onReceive:354 
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 4865): LOG: Warning Unknown dock level ignored.
W/System.err( 5147): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path: /storage/emulated/0
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:46)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.StatFs.<init>(StatFs.java:39)
W/System.err( 5147):    at com.mridang.storage.StorageWidget.getExternalTotalMemory(StorageWidget.java:45)
W/System.err( 5147):    at com.mridang.storage.StorageWidget.onUpdateData(StorageWidget.java:71)
W/System.err( 5147):    at com.google.android.apps.dashclock.api.DashClockExtension$1$1.run(DashClockExtension.java:312)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/System.err( 5147): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: statvfs failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/Settings( 5360): Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
W/System.err( 5147):    at libcore.io.Posix.statvfs(Native Method)
W/System.err( 5147):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.statvfs(ForwardingOs.java:132)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:44)
W/System.err( 5147):    ... 8 more
W/System.err( 5147): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path: /storage/emulated/0
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:46)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.StatFs.<init>(StatFs.java:39)
W/System.err( 5147):    at com.mridang.storage.StorageWidget.getExternalTotalMemory(StorageWidget.java:45)
W/System.err( 5147):    at com.mridang.storage.StorageWidget.onUpdateData(StorageWidget.java:72)
W/System.err( 5147):    at com.google.android.apps.dashclock.api.DashClockExtension$1$1.run(DashClockExtension.java:312)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/System.err( 5147): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: statvfs failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/CursorWindow( 2873): Window is full: requested allocation 228 bytes, free space 171 bytes, window size 2097152 bytes
W/System.err( 5147):    at libcore.io.Posix.statvfs(Native Method)
W/System.err( 5147):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.statvfs(ForwardingOs.java:132)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:44)
W/System.err( 5147):    ... 8 more
W/System.err( 5147): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path: /storage/emulated/0
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:46)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.StatFs.<init>(StatFs.java:39)
W/System.err( 5147):    at com.mridang.storage.StorageWidget.getExternalFreeMemory(StorageWidget.java:146)
W/System.err( 5147):    at com.mridang.storage.StorageWidget.onUpdateData(StorageWidget.java:85)
W/System.err( 5147):    at com.google.android.apps.dashclock.api.DashClockExtension$1$1.run(DashClockExtension.java:312)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/System.err( 5147): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: statvfs failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 5147):    at libcore.io.Posix.statvfs(Native Method)
W/System.err( 5147):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.statvfs(ForwardingOs.java:132)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:44)
W/System.err( 5147):    ... 8 more
W/System.err( 5147): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path: /storage/emulated/0
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:46)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.StatFs.<init>(StatFs.java:39)
W/System.err( 5147):    at com.mridang.storage.StorageWidget.getExternalTotalMemory(StorageWidget.java:45)
W/System.err( 5147):    at com.mridang.storage.StorageWidget.onUpdateData(StorageWidget.java:85)
W/System.err( 5147):    at com.google.android.apps.dashclock.api.DashClockExtension$1$1.run(DashClockExtension.java:312)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/System.err( 5147): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: statvfs failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err( 5147):    at libcore.io.Posix.statvfs(Native Method)
W/System.err( 5147):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.statvfs(ForwardingOs.java:132)
W/System.err( 5147):    at android.os.StatFs.doStat(StatFs.java:44)
W/System.err( 5147):    ... 8 more
W/HangoutsWidget( 5299): Unable to access destination database
E/DatabaseUtils( 2873): Writing exception to parcel
E/DatabaseUtils( 2873): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/DatabaseUtils( 2873):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.buildUnionSubQuery(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:540)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2873):     at com.android.providers.telephony.MmsSmsProvider.getConversations(MmsSmsProvider.java:815)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2873):     at com.android.providers.telephony.MmsSmsProvider.query(MmsSmsProvider.java:315)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2873):     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:857)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2873):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:200)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2873):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2873):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
E/DatabaseUtils( 2873):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918): Error accessing conversations cursor in SMS/MMS provider
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1471)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:185)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:420)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:461)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:404)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at com.google.android.apps.dashclock.phone.SmsExtension.tryOpenMmsSmsCursor(SmsExtension.java:242)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at com.google.android.apps.dashclock.phone.SmsExtension.onUpdateData(SmsExtension.java:104)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at com.google.android.apps.dashclock.api.DashClockExtension$1$1.run(DashClockExtension.java:312)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/dashclock_SmsExtension( 4918):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
W/GCoreFlp( 3247): No location to return for getLastLocation()
```

Comment: I also suggest looking at ANTLR. Some kind of regex might also do the job. It's odd that it looks like there's no log level in the log. That's usually the best way to distinguish log message types.

Comment: I've found the grammar for parsing stacktraces in ANTLR but having no experience with it seems to be a big roadblock. The log-level is there, it's the first character, followed by the slash.

Comment: Oh so why don't you just parse the lines that start with `E`?

Comment: You can keep the previous line in memory to get the message right before those.

Comment: You can use something like parboiled

Answer (score 1):

You can look for `:\tat`, remove the text before the `:`.  `\t` is a tab character.

You can also include the text from the line before and the line after if it has `:\t...`

e.g.

```
String prev = null;
while ((strLine = bufLogcat.readLine()) != null) {
    String curr = strLine.split(":", 2);
    if (curr.startsWith("\tat ")) {
       if (prev != null)
          System.out.println(prev);
       System.out.println(curr);
       prev = null;
    } else if (curr.startsWith("\t... ") && prev == null) {
       System.out.println(curr);
    } else {
       prev = curr;
    }
}
```